# What will be the frequency , start and end of ts function in Time series with observations in milliseconds per day

Tags: r, time-series

I have tried other solutions made in previous post. I am using R for timeseries.  My data has 100 millisec interval for each data point in a day. Total time is 2 months. What will be the frequency in this case? I used 864000.  If I want to use start as starting time with milliseconds part how can I do that?

```
var               starttime
1 281.9110 2020-08-10 08:35:04.000
2 281.9110 2020-08-10 08:35:04.100
3 281.9110 2020-08-10 08:35:04.200
4 281.8511 2020-08-10 08:35:04.300
5 281.7913 2020-08-10 08:35:04.400
```

The data is collected for a month now and the data points comes in every 100 millisecond. It is already a big size now. I tried below code but ended up in the output shown below:

```
 newdf_Long<-newdf_Long[,1] 
 mymts = ts(newdf_Long,start =(as.POSIXct("2020-08-10 08:35:04.000",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")),
       end = (as.POSIXct("2020-09-07 13:01:41.000",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")))

 Time Series:
   Start = 1597041304 
   End = 1599476501 
   Frequency = 1 
   [1] 136.5843 135.5664 133.5305
```

I want to know if I am giving right start end in ts function? What will be frequency in this case? After that when I tried to decompose it says

```
   "Error in decompose(mymts) : time series has no or less than 2 periods"
```

My objective with this data is to forecast drift everyday or in weekly basis.
Can anyone please guide me? I am a beginner.
Thanks

Comment: are you using standard ts() objects?

Comment: Yes I am trying to use that. I tried xts but after xts I could not decompose the signal.